# Extract public key from certificate asyncio python3

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, python-asyncio, x509

I used to get the public key from the client in an SSL exchange by calling getpeercert(binaryform=True) and then
cert = x509.Certificate.load(der)
pubkey= cert.public_key.unwrap()

But now I'm using asyncio and to get the certificate I call certClient=writer.get_extra_info('peercert').
I can't pass the binaryform parameter anymore and therefore dont know how to extract the public key from this.
Thank you very much

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.BaseTransport.get_extra_info) you should be able to use `get_extra_info('ssl_object')`  to get the underlying SSLSocket and then call `getpeercert` on this as you used to do. Did not try it though, therefore just a comment and not an answer.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much !